# Broadcom Wireless won't install at all! 12.04.3 Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

BroadCom BCM43227 802.11b/g/

ifconfig shows only eth0 and lo. No wlan0 shows.

I need this problem fixed soon, because I need to be able to take this laptop to do my work.

I tried all of the options on this:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

I've installed kernel source, and tried reinstalling the b43, but none of it takes effect. I can't be sure, but I've probably tried it with turning my laptop on for wifi. It has a button to turn it on and off, but it should auto enable with "enable networking".

But, I still can't install any drivers, nor can I get access to my WiFi. My laptop is right next to the router by Verizon. It is fast enough and I have accessed wifi through my Windows OS. But I can't get it to work on this OS.

I'm sorry, I'm really confused about everything. I'm also pretty new to Linux.